# mousemove events in gwt-openlayers

Tags: openlayers, gwt-openlayers

I am trying to capture mouse events in gwt-openlayers.
The following handler does receive events, however I am
unable to extract mouse position from EventObject object.
Anybody can help ?

```
mapPanel.getMap().getEvents().register("mousemove", mapPanel.getMap(), new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onHandle(EventObject eventObject) {
                // how to obtain mouse position ?
            }
        });
```

Also, is there another way to receive mouse move events ? Can I intercept
MousePosition Control for this ?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 9):

I went through the source code and found an answer myself. I hope it can be useful to somebody else.

```
mapPanel.getMap().getEvents().register("mousemove", mapPanel.getMap(), new EventHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onHandle(EventObject eventObject) {
                 JSObject xy = eventObject.getJSObject().getProperty("xy");
                 Pixel px = Pixel.narrowToPixel(xy);
                 LonLat lonlat = mapPanel.getMap().getLonLatFromPixel(px);
            }
        });
```